# Run code only on test

Tags: java, testing

I would like to execute a method only on test running.

This is a completion of integration test. When I run integration test, I want to generate a json file with the state of an Object.

I think of doing something like this in my code :

```
if(environnement == TEST) {
   // save object as json
}
```

Do you know other method to do this ? less crapy ?

Regards

Comment: You could move the equality test into its own function called something like "testingIsOn". You'll need to be more specific as to what "less crappy" means.

Comment: @Carcigenicate : Less crappy because I have to add specific code in my code for test validation :/

Comment: @SeniorJD What do you purpose ?

Comment: I smell some abstraction, although I've never had to do this, so I don't know what it will look like, sorry.

Comment: keep it simple. some times `if(environnement == TEST)` better than new class hierarchy and patterns

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `Polymorphism` OOP feature?

```
abstract class MyObject {
    void doSomething();
}

class MyObjectImpl {
    void doSomething() {
        // real implementation
    }
}

class MyObjectTest {
    void doSomething() {
        // create your json or other test functional
    }
}

class MyObjectFactory {
    static getMyObject(Environment env) {
        if (env == Environment.TEST) {
            return new MyObjectTest();
        } else {
            return new MyObjectImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I was sure my entire life that it is. But because of U, I'm not really sure too now. Thanks =\

Comment: It looks like a factory for me.

Comment: @SeniorJD Proxy should have reference to a real subject and delegate operation call to this subject. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Comment: @dit Yeah I got it, thanks. * has gone to rename all my proxy-named classes *

Comment: In our corporate environment this method would be banned because risk controls block any test code from being deployed to production.

Answer (score 0):

I generally provide test 'hooks' using this pattern

```
public class MyObject {

    public void doStuff() {
        // stuff to do

        onCompleteStuff();
    }

    protected void onCompleteStuff() {
    }
}
```

Then in the test code you can create a subclass of `MyObject` that does your test-only actions:

```
private MyObject newMyObject() {
 return new MyObject() {
   @Override
   protected void onCompleteStuff() {
       saveObjectAsJson();
   }
 };
}
```

This has the advantage of keeping test code out of your main build. It will also work if you must use a mock in your tests. For example, using the excellent Mockito library:

```
MyObject foo=Mockito.spy(new MyObject());

doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    saveObjectToJson();
    return null;
  }
}).when(foo).onCompleteStuff();
```

Comment: Sorry, but if I would see this code in real life I probably gonna beat its` author.